# Toolbar inside Fragments is leaking

Tags: android, memory-leaks, fragment, toolbar

I have an app that has a separate `toolbar` for each `Fragment`. Then the app sets it into Activity with `setSupportActionBar` method. Apparently this causes Fragment layout to leak after `onDestroyView`.

What I have tried is

1. setting `activity.setSupportActionBar(null)` which cause issues since `Navigation` library has following sequence of events: new Fragment is created and old calls onDestroyView. So putting the above code in onDestroyView causes the `supportActiobBar` to be null.
2. considered having one toolbar which is not easy since requires major refactoring and this is not my personal project.
3. setting `toolbar` to null. Doesn't work cause `ViewBinding` doesn't allow that.

**The questions is - is there any other way to mitigate the memory leak in this case.**

Comment: So why are you using `setSupportActionBar` at all when you can use the [Toolbar APIs](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/appbar#fragment) directly?

Comment: that's a very valid comment, I think you need to make that piece of docs in red and bold lol @ianhanniballake I will check the Toolbar APIs

Comment: that answers my question thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As per the [Fragment-owned app bar documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/appbar#fragment):

> When using a fragment-owned app bar, we strongly recommended using the `Toolbar` APIs directly. Do not use `setSupportActionBar()` and the Fragment menu APIs, which are appropriate only for activity-owned app bars.

In most cases, you can rely solely on the `Toolbar` APIs like `inflateMenu` and skip setting `setSupportActionBar()` at all.